# How to get the callback of Download Complete a file using Dio in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I have this code

```
 await dio.download(fileUrl, "${fileDir.path}/$fileName",
          onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
        if (total != -1) {
          print("Rec: $received , Total: $total");
          debugPrint("Directory path : " + filePath + "/" + fileName);
          setState(() {
            downloadProgressString =
                ((received / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
          });
        }
      });
```

Like *onReceiveProgress*, do we have any other callback for '**Download Complete**'?

Comment: https://pub.dev/documentation/dio/latest/dio/Dio/download.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The future it returns *is* the callback.

```
  await dio.download(fileUrl, "${fileDir.path}/$fileName",
      onReceiveProgress: (received, total) {
    if (total != -1) {
      print("Rec: $received , Total: $total");
      debugPrint("Directory path : " + filePath + "/" + fileName);
      setState(() {
        downloadProgressString =
            ((received / total) * 100).toStringAsFixed(0) + "%";
      });
    }
  });
  // HERE
  print("download complete!");
```

Comment: What if there is network interruption while downloading a file?

Comment: If something is thrown, it will bypass the print("download complete"). So, whoever calls this will receive the exception and "download complete" won't be printed.